# super user group or user?

Tags: sudo, users, root, su

I am using the following command in Oracle Exadata:

```
     sudo su - odiadmin
```

As sudo prompts for my own password, I am wondering if I upgrade myself to super user or do I switch to superuser 'odiadmin'. Also, is odiadmin a superuser group or just another user.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` runs a given command as superuser (i.e. `root`). The command it runs is `su - odiadmin`, which [substitutes the user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29) `odiadmin` - so that is another user, not a group, and it itself is not a superuser in the sense that `root` is.

The `-` flag to `su` makes it a login shell, and you aren't running a specific command as that user, so you're dropped into a new shell as that user - essentially the same as if you'd started a new session as that user via `telnet` or `ssh`.

The effect is also the same as if you'd just done `su - odiadmin`, but if you did that you'd need to know the password for that account. Using `sudo` means you only have to know your own password, which makes life simpler for you, but requires the `sudo` service to be configured to allow you to issue the `su` command, so there are potentially security implications if that isn't done properly.

So... you upgrade yourself to superuser (`root`) but only to switch to the non-superuser `odiadmin` account. When you're in the shell as `odiadmin` you do not have any `root` privileges, or any of your original account's privileges For example, you can only see files that are owned by `odiamdin`, or in groups that `odiadmin` is also in, or that are world-readable. You probably can't see files in your own home directory, if that has sensible permissions like 700. And you can't run any root-only executables like `useradd`. You are not `root` after you run that command.